# Looking for Segmentation Fault in C script

Tags: pointers, clang

Hi trying to learn C specifically how to use pointers.
I wrote this script to practice ideas I've learned, but it crashes with **segmentation fault error**.
Bit of research search suggests that I am trying to access something that I should not be accessing I think that is an uninitialized pointer but I can't find it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct IntItem {
  struct IntItem* next;
  int value;
};

struct IntList {
 struct IntItem* head;
 struct IntItem* tail;
};

void append_list(struct IntList* ls, int item){
  struct IntItem* last = ls->tail;
  struct IntItem addition = {NULL,item};

  last->next = &addition;
  ls->tail = &addition;

  if (!ls->head) {
    ls->head = &addition;
  }
}

int sum(int x, int y){
  return x + y;
}

int max(int x, int y){
  return x*(x>y) + y*(y>x);
}

int reduce(struct IntList xs, int (*opy)(int, int)){
  struct IntItem current = *xs.head;
  int running = 0;

  while (current.next) {
    running = opy(running,current.value);
    current = *current.next;
  }
  return running;
}

int main(void) {
  struct IntList ls = {NULL, NULL};

  printf("Start Script\n");
  append_list(&ls, 1);
  append_list(&ls, 2);
  append_list(&ls, 3);
  printf("List Complete\n");

  printf("Sum: %i",reduce(ls,sum));
  printf("Max: %i",reduce(ls,max));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: run it though GDB, and inspect variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- When you call `append_list(&ls, 1)`, then inside `append_list`, what is the value of `last`?
- What does `last->next = &addition` do?

And for your next bug:

- What happens to `addition` after `append_list` returns?  What does that mean for pointers to it?

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful.

Comment: I believe that I've caught on to the second bug that you alluded to.